# Getting a few errors in my console from my code

Tags: mysql, bukkit

I am coding a stats plugin that on join, retrieves the stats from a database, implements them into a hash map, and on quit it implements those new stats into the database, the reason for this is so there isn't as much lag as opening connections every second.

If this means anything, I am using MariaDB.

HashMaps Below

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> kills = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public static HashMap<String, Integer> deaths = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Code Below

```
   @EventHandler
public void onDeath(PlayerDeathEvent event){
    Player p = event.getEntity();
    Player k = p.getKiller();
    kills.put(k.getName(), kills.get(k.getName() + 1));
    deaths.put(p.getName(), deaths.get(p.getName() + 1));
    removeScoreboard(p);
    setScoreboard(p);
    removeScoreboard(k);
    setScoreboard(k);
}

@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    OfflinePlayer p2 = e.getPlayer();
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    openConnection();
    try{
        int previousDeaths = 0;
        int previousKills = 0;

        if(playerDataContainsPlayer(p)){
            PreparedStatement sql = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT deaths FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?;");
            PreparedStatement sql2 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT kills FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?;");

            ResultSet result = sql.executeQuery();
            ResultSet result2 = sql2.executeQuery();
            result2.next();
            result.next();

            previousDeaths = result.getInt("deaths");
            previousKills = result2.getInt("kills");

            kills.put(p.getName(), previousKills);
            deaths.put(p.getName(), previousDeaths);

            sql.close();
            sql2.close();
            result.close();
            result2.close();
            removeScoreboard(p);
            setScoreboard(p);
        } else {
            PreparedStatement newPlayer = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `player_data` values(?,0,0);");
            newPlayer.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            newPlayer.setInt(2, 0);
            newPlayer.setInt(3, 0);
            newPlayer.execute();
            newPlayer.close();
            kills.put(p.getName(), 0);
            deaths.put(p.getName(), 0);
            removeScoreboard(p);
            setScoreboard(p);
        }

    }catch(Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        closeConnection();
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onLeave(PlayerQuitEvent e){
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    openConnection();
    try{
        int previousDeaths = 0;
        int previousKills = 0;

        if(playerDataContainsPlayer(p)){
            PreparedStatement sql = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT deaths FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?;");
            PreparedStatement sql2 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT kills FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?;");
            sql.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            sql2.setString(1, p.getUniqueId().toString());

            ResultSet result = sql.executeQuery();
            ResultSet result2 = sql2.executeQuery();
            result2.next();
            result.next();

            previousDeaths = result.getInt("deaths");
            previousKills = result2.getInt("kills");

            PreparedStatement killsUpdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `player_data` SET kills=? WHERE player=?;");
            killsUpdate.setInt(1, kills.get(p.getName()));
            killsUpdate.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            killsUpdate.executeUpdate();

            PreparedStatement deathsUpdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `player_data` SET deaths=? WHERE player=?;");
            deathsUpdate.setInt(1, deaths.get(p.getName()));
            deathsUpdate.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
            deathsUpdate.executeUpdate();

            deathsUpdate.close();
            killsUpdate.close();
            sql.close();
            sql2.close();
            result.close();
            result2.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        closeConnection();
    }
}
```

Whenever you join, it says [20:51:43 WARN]: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

And whenever you kill someone, or die, your kills are then null and your deaths are then null. I am not sure why this is happening, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have not set parameters for PreparedStatement to where condition.

```
PreparedStatement sql = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT deaths FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?");
PreparedStatement sql2 = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT kills FROM `player_data` WHERE player=?");
```

Set parameters according where conditions data types.
Eg: preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);

Refer this:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

For second question:

Pls set hashmap values as follows

```
        previousDeaths = result.getInt("deaths");
        previousKills = result2.getInt("kills");

        kills.put(p.getName(), previousKills);
        deaths.put(p.getName(), previousDeaths);

        PreparedStatement killsUpdate = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE `player_data` SET kills=? WHERE player=?;");
        killsUpdate.setInt(1, kills.get(p.getName()));
        killsUpdate.setString(2, p.getUniqueId().toString());
        killsUpdate.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: and do you know why the HashMaps aren't working?

Comment: Also, I don't want to set Integers on Join, I want to retrieve the integers, and save them on Leave.

Comment: What is the problem with hashmap?

Comment: What the the "player" column datatype?

Comment: I had another question, but whenever someone kills someone or dies the hashmap is set to null, it doesn't go up in integers, Also, I don't want to set Integers on Join, I want to retrieve the integers, and save them on Leave. I don't get what you're trying to get me to fix.

Comment: SELECT deaths FROM `player_data` WHERE player=? here you have where condition with player.  So you should set value for WHERE condition

Comment: I fixed that part. onLeave I also get a NullPointerException.

Comment: can you paste first line of exception here? Which line do you get exception?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at sql.StatEvents.onLeave(StatEvents.java:205), which basically is the line that does: killsUpdate.setInt(1, kills.get(p.getName()));

I think the reason it turns an error is because the HashMap is null, which I don't know why, and am hoping you can help me with.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Pls debug code and check why this is null.

Comment: Here not hashmap null. The problem is there is no key for p.getName(). Pls check this point.

Comment: Problem is I checked and I do not know why it is null.

Comment: I added part of code above. You have not set values to hashmaps inside onleave method. I corrected it above.Pls check. If you receive correct answer pls mark this as correct answer.

Comment: That's no different then the code I have?

Comment: According to above code you have not set values for hashmaps inside onleave method

Comment: Yes I do? I have that in the onLeave method, I don't want to put kills to put previousKills on leave, only on join to load the stats.

Comment: Then set directly as  killsUpdate.setInt(1, previousKills );
 deathsUpdate.setInt(1, previousDeaths );

Comment: Not working, I tested a previously working plugin and it's not working, I may just start from scratch.

Comment: Pls mark this as correct if you got the answer.

Comment: I haven't gotten an answer that works yet.